# Import Asana project in Notion missing images?

Tags: asana

I'm trying to use Notion’s native import function to import Asana projects into my Notion account. In the past it worked as included images and docs like pdf’s. Now when I import all of the pictures are replaced with long URLs that when clicked, returns no access.

Does anyone have a workaround for this or having the same issue?